# Как в шаблоне вида (layout) Yii2 вывести данные из модели Active Record?

Tags: php, yii2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный способ как работать с моделью Active Record именно в шаблоне Yii2. Хочу вывести список жанров в шапке сайта. Если бы это требовалось сделать в виде(views), то тут было бы все просто, через модель и контроллер.
Наверняка делать что то типа $genres =  Genres::find()->all() в самом шаблоне неправильно. Как решить эту ситуацию?

Comment: можно создать просто виджет, где ты пропишешь - $genres = Genres::find()->all(), и в шаблоне просто вызывать данный виджет

Answer (score 0):

В контролере:
Yii::$app->params['test'] = $needvar;
В layout: Yii::$app->params['test'];